# Calculate the length of itab structure in bytes

Tags: database, oracle, abap, sap-bw, sap-data-dictionary

The internal table size (e.g. for a DSO) is limited to 4030 bytes. I have a list of infoobjects and would like to calculate if their amount will exceed this limit. How can I convert their data type in bytes?

Example:

```
CHAR 4 -> xxx bytes
DATS   -> xxx bytes
FLTP   -> xxx bytes
...
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you work in a Unicode system?

Comment: Yes, it is a unicode system

Comment: What is the context, what is the exact goal? Because the "size of a structure" may have several answers, especially if you need to take into account the [alignment gaps](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenalignment.htm).

Comment: Limit of 4030 bytes is for any transparent table in the ABAP Dictionary after ABAP 6.20 dixit [note 355898](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/355898).

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the `ls_bkpf` with the actual structure (line of internal table) you use in your program, oherwise I hope it helps. lv_length will contain the total size of the fields in bytes.

```
  DATA: ls_bkpf TYPE bkpf.
  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lv_field> TYPE any.
  DATA: lo_typedesc TYPE REF TO cl_abap_typedescr.
  DATA: lv_length TYPE i.

  DO.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index
           OF STRUCTURE ls_bkpf
           TO <lv_field>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      lo_typedesc = cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_data( <lv_field> ).
      ADD lo_typedesc->length TO lv_length.
    ELSE.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.
```

Comment: In Unicode systems characters are stored on 2 bytes, so a MANDT field has _length 3_ but _occupies 6 bytes_. NUMC, DAT, FLTP is unchanged.